# how to align this

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment

I'm using this

```
\newcommand\Underset[2]{\underset{\textstyle #1}{#2}}
```

so that

```
\Underset{f \mapsto f\circ \partial_{n} }{\partial^{*}_{n}:Hom(G_{n-1},M)\to Hom(G_{n},M)}
```

wouldn't minimize the function under those sets, but now how do I align `f` under `Hom` and the row `\mapsto` under the row `\to`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you please post a small compilable code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are looking for but, well, like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\partial^{*}_{n}:\Hom(G_{n-1},M)&\to\Hom(G_{n},M)\\
f &\mapsto f\circ \partial_{n}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: basically yes, but why do we need to define a math operator? I mean why \DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom} is needed in order to have an allingment

Comment: @DavideTrono It is not needed to have the alignment. However, it is needed overall. If you write only `Hom`, I will understand it as *H* x *o* x *m*, i.e. a product of three variables. `\DeclareMathOperator` makes it in roman font (which is needed) and produces a little space after the operator (which looks nice and is recommended).